# AWK SubRecords (records inside records)

Tags: awk

What is the best way of processing records inside records in awk?

I have records starting with

```
Network: 125
 <junk data>
  MAC: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA
  Packets: 5125
 <junk data>
   Client: 1
     <junk data>
      MAC: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:c4
      Packets: 942
     <junk data>
   Client: 2
     <junk data>
      MAC: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:fa
      Packets: 1052
     <junk data>
 <junk data>
Network: 126
...
```

## Expected output

```
---------------------------
Network: 125
Client: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:c4
Packets: 942
---------------------------

---------------------------
Network: 125
Client: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:fa
Packets: 1052
---------------------------
```

Note: The output musn't include any data from the Network body itself like MAC: AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA.

First I have to set the

{ RS = "Network" ; FS = "\n" }
  Then do some criteria matching, then I have to examine the Client subrecords and also do some criteria matching and if that matches, only print out certain fields from this internal record.

Is there an RSS "Sub record" function in awk?

Also there is a problem with awk's ~32000 fields NF limitation. The data I have to process is lot more than that.

Thanks!

Comment: You can split the records based on another delimiter: `split($1,a,":")` would slice `$1` based on delimiter `:` and store in the array `a`.

Comment: Are the indents consistent ?

Comment: Nope, both the network records, both the client records can have more/less fields and it's not xml just plain txt file.

Comment: How do you recognize the <useful data I need>. Could you put a more practical example input?

Comment: Still don't really know what you want but you could try something like `awk '/^Network/{a=$0}/[ ]+Client/{b=$0}/<useful/{print a,b,$0}' file`

Comment: Well the problem is, why I need a second record is because the Network record itself holds info what's identical to the client records. Like there is a field Packets: what I need but only from the Client sections, while it's present in the Network section body itself. I need basically 2 subfields from all the clients which match certain criteria, MAC address, packets and nothing else.

Comment: @user3796932 Update your question to Show what the original data is and what your expected output is

Comment: Done it's updated as you requested sir.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this does what you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=": "; hr="----------------" }
!h {print hr; h=1} 
/Network/ {n=$2} 
/Client/ {c=1} 
c && /MAC/ {m=$2} 
c && /Packets/ {p=$2} 
m && p {
    print "Network", n
    print "Client", m 
    print "Packets", p
    print hr "\n"
    m=c=p=h=""
}' input
```

- When the `h` flag is false, print the horizontal rule.
- Save network to `n`
- Set client flag to true only when within a client
- Save client MAC to `m`
- Save packets to `p`
- When `m` and `p` are set, print output and unset flags.

Output:

```
----------------
Network: 125
Client: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:c4
Packets: 942
----------------

----------------
Network: 125
Client: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:fa
Packets: 1052
----------------
```

This works for the input you have shown but in case the number of spaces between the `Name: Value` may vary, you might want to change the Field Separator `FS="[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]+"` (zero or more space characters, a colon, then one or more space characters). Due to the fact that the MAC address also contains colon, the field separator must contain at least one space at the moment. If that's a problem, let me know.

Comment: Very good one, also upvoting for the fact it is an answer with a (proper) explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Awk:

```
gawk -v RS='Network: ' -F 'Client: ' -v hl=--------------------------- '{gsub(/\n.*$/, "", $1); for(i=2;i<=NF;++i){if(match($i, /.*MAC: ([[:alnum:]:]+).*Packets: ([0-9]+).*/, a)) printf "%s\nNetwork: %s\nClient: %s\nPackets: %s\n%s\n\n", hl, $1, a[1], a[2], hl } }' file
```

Script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {
    RS = "Network: "
    FS = "Client: "
    hl = "---------------------------"
}
{
    gsub(/\n.*$/, "", $1)
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
        if (match($i, /.*MAC: ([[:alnum:]:]+).*Packets: ([0-9]+).*/, a))
            printf "%s\nNetwork: %s\nClient: %s\nPackets: %s\n%s\n\n", hl, $1, a[1], a[2], hl
}
```

Output:

```
---------------------------
Network: 125
Client: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:c4
Packets: 942
---------------------------

---------------------------
Network: 125
Client: 30:85:a9:b0:ec:fa
Packets: 1052
---------------------------
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in awk

```
awk '/^Network/{a=$0}/    MAC:/{b=$2}
/    Packets/{print"------------------------------\n" a"\n","Client: "b"\n",$0"\n------------------------------"}' file
```

Another way that sets flags on clients.

```
awk 'BEGIN{c="------------------------------\n"}
{gsub(/[ ][ ]+/,"")}
/^Network/{a=$0;x=0}
/Client/{x=1}
x&&/MAC:/{b=$2}
x&&/Packets/{print c a"\n","Client: "b"\n",$0"\n"c}' file
```